# Running of the Higgs coupling

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, higgs

Why is the coupling constant of the Higgs potential not a constant, but a running constant?

In other words, why is
$$\lambda (h) \sim \lambda_{0} - \frac{y_{t}}{16\pi^{2}}\text{ln}\left(\frac{h^{2}}{m^{2}}\right) + \frac{\lambda_{0}^{2}}{16\pi^{2}}\text{ln}\left(\frac{h^{2}}{m^{2}}\right)+\cdots,$$
where $\lambda_{0}$ is the bare coupling and $y_{t}={m_{t}}/{v}$, where $m_{t}$ is the mass of the top quark and $v$ is the Higgs vacuum expectation value?

Comment: Hi! In general, in QFT all coupling constants are running. I don't understand whether you are familiar with this concept and you just want to know about the Higgs in particular or if it is the first time that you hear of a running coupling.

Comment: I would like to know about the Higgs specificallly.

Comment: @failexam have you learnt about renormalization and qft?

Comment: Ok, then why do you expect it not to be running? Loop diagrams arising from the Higgs sector diverge even worse than e.g. QED loops, and so you need renormalization and so on.. I don't thing I am able to give you a complete answer, but if you are familiar with the QFT language this is an excellent reference: http://www.sciencedirect.com.ezproxy.its.uu.se/science/article/pii/0370157389900616

Comment: Do I need to study non-abelian gauge theories to be able to understand the running of the Higgs coupling via renormalisation group flow?

Comment: Have you studied phi-4 theory? It's the canonical QFT. You'll see the quartic running.

Comment: Also you can vote to reopen your own question.